# java calling method fails as method undefined

Tags: java, methods, undefined

I have a method written which checks a specific file to count how many lines it has:

```
public int countFileRecords() 

        {
        Scanner in = new Scanner (new FileInputStream("src/data/VinylRecords.txt"));
        int lines = -1;
        while (in.hasNextLine()) //loop while there is a new line
        {lines +=1; // add one to my counter
        in.nextLine();} // move to the next line and loop again
        return lines;
        }
```

but when I try and call this from another class I get an error "the method is undefined for the type"

```
public class Test 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
{
System.out.println(countFileRecords());
}
```

I am still learning java and I think I need to do something to tell this class what to call.

I want to be able to call and run the method to check the current number of lines int he files - But I thought all the information was in the method so this should work.  I would like to understand why it does not so I can correct it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Test 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
{
System.out.println(countFileRecords());
}
```

Calling the method like that (using just the name of the method to call it) will not compile , you can inside a static method call another static method in the same class , or an imported static method declared in another class.

So you should make the countFileRecords method static in the declaration ( adding static keyword) and then import using import static to can call it directly using the just the method name :

---

```
package com;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static int countFileRecords() 
    {
        Scanner in=null;
        try {
            in = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("src/data/VinylRecords.txt"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        int lines = -1;
        while (in.hasNextLine()) // loop while there is a new line
        {
            lines += 1; // add one to my counter
            in.nextLine();
        } // move to the next line and loop again
        return lines;
    }
}
```

---

```
package com;

import static com.Main.countFileRecords;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(countFileRecords());
    }
}
```